# Android añadir botón intercambiable en un Menú

Tags: java, android, android-layout, menú

Tengo el siguiente elemento en el menú

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_list_grid"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:title="Ver en rejilla" />
```

me gustaría añadir un icono pero que dependiendo si está activado o no muestre un icono `lista` o `rejilla`

Answer (score 1):

puedes cambiar la imagen del icono con un Selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/some_icon" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/some_icon"/>
</selector>
```

Luego lo usas así.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:icon="@drawable/some_selector />

</menu>
```

de igual forma te paso el link de la documentación :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=es-419

saludos.

Comment: solo cambia cuando lo mantienes pulsado con el dedo, e intentado poner  android:state_checked="true" y no funciona